# Why does TS complain when composing generic functions with @type and not @param and @return?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

Why does TS complain about this:

```js
/**
 * @template X
 * @type {function(X): X}
 */
const identity1 = (x) => x;

/**
 * @template X
 * @type {function(X): X}
 */
const identity2 = (x) => identity1(x);
```

TypeScript error message:

```
Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'X'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
  'X' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'X'.ts(2719)
graph.mjs(4, 14): This type parameter might need an `extends X` constraint.
const identity1: (arg0: X) => X
@template X
@type — {function(X): X}
```

However when changing the `@type` with `@param` and `@return` it works fine:

```js
/**
 * @template X
 * @param {X} x
 * @returns {X}
 */
const identity1 = (x) => x;

/**
 * @template X
 * @type {function(X): X}
 */
const identity2 = (x) => identity1(x);
```

I don't understand why. The [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) does not mention how these two signatures may interact differently with generic types.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of types referenced with the `@type` tag is limited to the curly braces. That is, `@type {function(X): X}`, doesn't reference a generic type because we refer to X outside the scope. At least that's my interpretation of it. Regardless, extraction of the provided type from `@type` isn't supported.

However, you can use `@typedef` to go beyond functions:

```js
/**  
* @template X  
* @typedef {X extends number ? [1, 2, 3][X] : never} Successor  
*/ 

/**  
* @template X  
* @typedef {X} Identity  
*/ 

/**
* @template X  
* @typedef {Identity<Identity<X>>} Identity2  
*/

/** @type {Successor<Identity<1>>} */ 
const x = 2;
```